# Can I call default constructor from parameterized constructor inside public class in java?

Tags: java

I want to call default constructor from a parameterized constructor inside a public java class.

Can I achieve it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `this();` in the first line of the parametrized constructor and it will call your default constructor. Make sure you have default constructor as compiler will not provide one if you declare a parametrized constructor.

Answer (score 8):

For Java: You might mean the constructor without parameters.
If so you can use the following code:

```
public class MyClass {
   // no params constructor 
   public MyClass() {
      ...
   }

   // parametrized constructor
   public MyClass(int p1, String p2) {
       this();
   }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It is worth noting that `this();` has to be the first line of the parameterised constructor - it doesn't work if you put other stuff first.

Answer (score 3):

You can just call default constructor with new operator (like this: new Test();) or this();.
just Test() is forbidden because its not a method of class.

```
package org.gpowork.test;

public class Test {
    private String field;
    private Long time = 0L; 
    public Test(){
        this.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Default constructor. "+this.time);
    }
    public Test(String field){
            this();
        Test instance = new Test();
        this.field = field;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("start...");
        Test t1 = new Test();
        System.out.println("-------");
        Test t2 = new Test("field1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the default constructor is the no-argument constructor that's implicitly provided by the compiler. And the compiler won't provide one in case you introduce any constructor with arguments.

In that case you have to explicitly define a no-argument constructor (which is not default by the way, because it's not provided by the compiler), e.g. `public MyClass() { }`.

And you can call it from other constructor as `this();`, which must be the first statement in the constructor where it's being called.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can

```
public YourClass() {
    public YourClass() { super();}
    public YourClass(int x) { this();}
}
```

provided you have the same argument constructor. This won't work

```
public YourClass() {
    public YourClass(int x, int y) { this(); } // compiler error here
    public YourClass(int x) { super(); }
}
```

Note: 
**super()** calls the super constructor (in this case, class Object, because MyClass extends Object implicitly and class Object has a no arg constructor) that matches the same number of arguments.

**this()** calls the constructor of the current class that matches the same number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a default constructor once you've created a constructor that takes arguments. You'll have to create the no argument constructor yourself in order to make a call from the parameterized constructor.

Comment: I have tried this & it is working:

 String name;

 Test() {
  System.out.println("Welcome");
 }

 Test(String input) {
  this();
  this.name = input;
  System.out.println(this.name);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Test("Hello");
 }

Comment: Yes, this will work. You have created the `Test()` no-arg constructor. That is what I was saying. The compiler doesn't provide the default no-arg constructor when you have created an arg constructor. The default constructor is the constructor that you don't have to write in the class explicitly. The compiler does the job for you. Try your code without the `Test()` constructor, it'll give an error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible but few points need to be followed.

1. Once you create a parameterized constructor java compiler will no longer provide a default constructor for object creation.
2. So calling it a default constructor would be an inappropriate name. It is called as 'No-args constructor'.
3. No-args constructor has to be explicitly written by you along with parameterized constructor in order to have a nested calls.
4. Call to one constructor from another needs always be made as the first instruction of the constructor.

```
public class Demo {
    Demo(){
        //Instructions...
    }

    Demo(Integer dummyArg){
        //First instruction should be constructor if there is one
        Demo(); 
        //Other instructions...
    }

    Demo(String dummyArg){
        //First instruction should be constructor if there is one
        this(); 
        //Other instructions...
    }

    Demo(Object dummyArg){
        //First instruction should be constructor if there is one
        this("Hello"); //call to constructor with String as arg 
        //Other instructions...
    }
}
```